# Binary Classification neural net predicts only one value for unseen data even after training using class weight

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, data-science

The Binary classifier I built has roc auc : 72% on training data and 78% on test data. However when I save the model parameters and score unseen imbalanced data, it predicts only one value for all data points.

Following is the model architecture

```
#Define Model
model = Sequential()
# Input layer
model.add(Dense(units = 512, activation = "relu", input_dim = input_dim, kernel_initializer = "normal", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.005), 
                kernel_constraint = max_norm(5.)))
# Add dropout regularization
##model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))

model.add(Dense(units = 512, activation = "relu", input_dim = input_dim, kernel_initializer = "normal", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.005), 
                kernel_constraint = max_norm(5.)))
# Add dropout regularization
##model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))

# First hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units = 256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.005), kernel_constraint=max_norm(5)))
# Add dropout regularization
##model.add(Dropout(rate=0.1))

# Second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.005), kernel_constraint=max_norm(5)))
# Add dropout regularization
##model.add(Dropout(rate=0.1))

# Third hidden layer
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05), kernel_constraint=max_norm(5)))
# Add dropout regularization
##model.add(Dropout(rate=0.1))

# Output layer
model.add(layers.Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',auc])
model.summary()
```

Class weights are defined as follows :

```
def get_class_weights(y):
    counter = Counter(y)
    majority = max(counter.values())
    return  {cls: round(float(majority)/float(count), 2) for cls, count in counter.items()}
```

For the unseen data it is only predicting 0.98 for all data points. Read a lot of literature on imbalanced data and tried everything. Its still not getting better. Appreciate any help/input.

Comment: How much imbalance is there in the training data.

Comment: @mujjiga : 85% of the data are 0's and rest 15% is 1's

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are probably due to overfitting.

You should start with a simple model and gradually add hidden layers. You can start even with a single dense layer with the sigmoid unit. An efficient way to prevent overfitting feed-forward networks is dropout. In fact, you should use it between all hidden layers. In the beginning, you should start without L2 regularization and kernel constraints and only if observe that the model is overfitting, add it.

Another reason why your model fails might be that it is hard to learn anything from your data. In this case, I would recommend standardizing the features, so they have zero mean and unit variance.

Comment: Thank you, I tried dropout layer and standarscaler, but the results did not change much. When I trained the model with original population without class balancing, the predictions are all different but close to 0's as thats the majority population. After training the data on balanced data, do we need to introduce prior distribution?

Comment: In theory, yes, but it never worked for me. What helped me in these cases was making the dataset slightly imbalanced in favor of the majority class. But this is a total alchemy for which I don't have much theoretical justification.